# Laravel BackPack translate rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

It is necessary to translate the displayed fields from the base.

For example, I have fields in the base name and surname for me now, when I go to the tab with them, they are written like this Name and Surname with a capital letter and I would like to translate them into another language.

Tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hei there,

You can simply just add into your name field this syntax:

```
CRUD::column('name')
    ->type('text')
    ->label(trans('lang_file.your_field_name')); // This line
```

You can check for more info in here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-trans

Best, Vreedom18